where can I find _bpy module?
In bpy module, there is code like this:

When import bpy, it will prompts error.
import bpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from _bpy import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bpy'

I searched local and google, can not find this.
How to find or install this module?
I am on ubuntu 22.04, blender 3.0.1.
While on my macbook, Blender4.2, Python console, I can import bpy and _bpy both ok, but I just have no way to figure out where _bpy is.

Download a newer version from blender.org, version 3.6.0, the same problem

When do you get this error? AFAIK the _bpy is not a Python module. There is no Python source code for it. It's a binary internal C++ module included in Blender. Python can call C/C++ functions. You can find functions in the source code of Blender. Here is a similar quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187025/blender-python-bpy-init-py-apparently-importing-from-a-non-existent-mod/37207627#37207627.
